# Kivy: self.parent.current not redirecting me to different screen using screen manager

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Using Kivymd, I am trying to make a button in the MDList go to a page, but when I try to set the on_release nothing happens. Someone please help. I need to be able to click the sign out button and for it to redirect me to the sign in screen perferably using a python function because I would like to also do other things after the button is clicked

main.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager

class SignInScreen(Screen):
    pass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ButtonGrid(ButtonBehavior, BoxLayout):
    pass

class AttendanceApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        #self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "LightBlue"
        #self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Red"
        return HomeScreen()
    def change_theme(self, primary_palette, accent_palette):
        pass
        #theme_cls = ThemeManager()
    def signin_pressed(self, instance):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    AttendanceApp().run()
```

Attendance.kv

```
# Filename: Attendance.kv

#:import utils kivy.utils

#screens

<SignInScreen>
 #code

<HomeScreen>
    NavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:

            Screen:

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "vertical"

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: "Home"
                        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_menu.set_state()]]
                        elevation: 10

                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Content"
                        halign: "center"
                        
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_menu

            MenuScreen:

ScreenManager:
    id: sm_menu

    SignInScreen:
        name: "signin"
    HomeScreen:
        name: "home"
    MenuScreen:
        name: "menu"

<MenuScreen>
        
    ScrollView:

        MDList:
            id: scroll

            OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
                id: menu_home
                text: "Home"
                elevation: 10

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "home"
            
            OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
                id: menu_schedule
                text: "Schedule"
                elevation: 10

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "calendar-month"
            
            OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
                id: menu_take
                text: "Take"
                elevation: 10

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "account-multiple"

            OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
                id: menu_rosters
                text: "Rosters"
                elevation: 10

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "clipboard-list-outline"

            OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
                id: menu_subs
                text: "Subs"
                elevation: 10

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "account-multiple-outline"
            
            OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
                id: menu_help
                text: "Help"
                elevation: 10

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "lightbulb-on-outline"

            OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
                id: menu_settings
                text: "Settings"
                elevation: 10

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "settings-outline"        

            OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
                id: menu_signout
                text: "Sign Out"
                elevation: 10
                on_release: "signin"

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "exit-to-app"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `kv` slightly for that `Button` like this:

```
        OneLineAvatarIconListItem:
            id: menu_signout
            text: "Sign Out"
            elevation: 10
            on_release: app.signout_pressed()

            IconLeftWidget:
                icon: "exit-to-app"
```

And in your `AttendanceApp`, add a method:

```
def signout_pressed(self):
    print('signout pressed')
    self.root.current = 'signin'
```

This assumes that the `root` of your `AttendanceApp` will be a `ScreenManager`.